# Вывод значений из MySQL-запроса

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

**Задача**

Нужно вывести значение одной ячейки на основании запроса пользователя в форме.

**Пример кода**

```
$season = $_GET["season"];
$series = $_GET["series"];   

$query = "SELECT 'description' FROM `series_description` WHERE season`='$season' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
  echo "<p>".$info['description']."</p>";
}
```

Вместо значения из ячейки я получаю такой HTML

```
<p>description</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените кавички в 'description' на

```
`description`
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает.